# Psycopg2 functions in parameters

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I'm wonder how I can pass a Postgres function to a field in an insert statement in Psycopg2. Looked everywhere in the doc but can't find the answer.

The code:

From the DBconn class:

```
def insert(self, table, data):

    fields = data.keys()
    sql = "INSERT INTO " + table + "("
    sql += ",".join(fields) + ") VALUES (" + ",".join(["%s"]*len(fields)) + ");"
    self.cur.execute(sql, data.values())
```

And when calling this function:

```
db.insert("tblpeople", {"person_name":"john", "org_id":"currval('tblorganisations_org_id_seq')"})
```

So the question is how can I tell Psycopg2 that the org_id value is a Postgres function?

Tnx!

Comment: You can do that (AsIs) but there will be no currval in the current session.

Comment: Doesn't work AsIs, I get a DataError: invalid input syntax for integer

Answer (score 0):

Your code is producing the statement:

```
INSERT INTO tblpeople (org_id,person_name) VALUES (%s,%s);
```

and you are passing 2 arguments.  That won't work.  You want to produce this code:

```
INSERT INTO tblpeople (org_id,person_name)
VALUES (currval('tblorganisations_org_id_seq'),%s);
```

and then pass a single argument.  I don't see any way of doing that with your current data structure.  If you add another piece of data to your dictionary, like:

```
{
    "text":{"person_name":"john"},
    "function":{"org_id":"currval('tblorganisations_org_id_seq')"}
}
```

and change your constructor to produce the proper query based upon the 'function' key, or, you could 'hard code' your query builder to recognize the 'currval(' being at the beginning of the value.  Anyway, the basic problem is you are passing the data as a string argument which won't be handled correctly.

-g

Comment: I found the solution, and Clodoaldo Neto, you were right, I only didn't fully understand what you said. This simply solves it:

    db.insert("tblpeople", {"person_name":"john doe", "org_id":AsIs("currval('tblorganisations_org_id_seq')")})

And the currval works when I do an insert on the tblorganisations table right before this one and within the same transaction.